# MySQL fulltext with stems

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, stemming

I am building a little search function for my site. I am taking my user's query, stemming the keywords and then running a fulltext MySQL search against the stemmed keywords.

The problem is that MySQL is treating the stems as literal. Here is the process that is happening:

1. user searches for a word like "baseballs"
2. my stemming algorithm (Porter Stemmer) turns "baseballs" into "basebal"
3. fulltext does not find anything matching "basebal", even though there SHOULD be matches for "baseball" and "baseballs"

How do I do the equivalent of LIKE 'basebal%' with fulltext?

EDIT:

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT MATCH (`title`,`body`) AGAINST ('basebal') AS `relevance`,`id` FROM `blogs` WHERE MATCH (`title`,`body`) AGAINST ('basebal') ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it will work with an asterisk at the end:  `basebal*`.  See the `*` operator on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for more info.

Comment: Kaled is doing full text search ... so he using MATCH

Comment: Kaleb, as Ragez pointed out, I am in fact doing a match query...to make it clearer, i will add it to the question

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that.  I did find a post that says that explains why postfix MATCH wildcards are not implemented.

Comment: just saw your new edit...tried it...BINGO. thanks for the repeated tried haha

Comment: LOL, now I misunderstood the MySQL reference.  Looks like an asterisk should work at the end, NOT at the beginning -- give that a try.

Comment: Awesome!  3rd time's a charm, LOL.  And I learned something about FULLTEXT wildcards.

Comment: Fulltext has wildcards BUT only in Boolean Mode

Answer (score 0):

See This link.. Stemming is not installed BY default in MySQL but you can install it your self..

http://oksoft.blogspot.com/2009/05/stemming-words-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

`IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` is the default mode and not compatible with stemming. Try `IN BOOLEAN MODE` with wildcards...

```
SELECT MATCH (`title`, `body`) AGAINST ('basebal*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`, `id` FROM `blogs` WHERE MATCH (`title`, `body`) AGAINST ('basebal*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

Example above provides clarity for people stumbling onto this question 10 years after it was asked. Topic is still relevant and benefits from complete examples