# Is it possible to stem full text match queries in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use wildcards to pass a stem of a word as part of a full text search in MySql.  I would prefer to use match...against for the performance benefit instead of a like query.

I found this post which makes it sound as though this can be done:
[MySQL fulltext with stems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062101/mysql-fulltext-with-stems)

...but I can't get it to work for me.

My data looks like this:

```
table name: "rxnorm_brands"
step_medname              bn_name
Amoxicillin               Wymox
Amoxicillin-Clavulanate   Augmentin
```

This query works but uses "like":

```
select `step_medname`, `bn_name`
from `rxnorm_brands`
where (`bn_name` like 'Amox%' or `step_medname` like 'Amox%');
```

I want to use this query, but it returns nothing:

```
select `step_medname`, `bn_name`
from `rxnorm_brands`
where MATCH (`bn_name`, `step_medname`) AGAINST ('Amox*');
```

I do have a fulltext index on bn_name and step_medname.  What am I doing wrong?  Or can this not be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using IN BOOLEAN MODE, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html.

So your query would become:

```
select `step_medname`, `bn_name`
from `rxnorm_brands`
where MATCH (`bn_name`, `step_medname`) AGAINST ('Amox*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but note that with the BOOLEAN MODE matching, rows either match or they don't - the results can no longer be ordered by relevance like they can with normal FULLTEXT searches.

Answer (score -1):

The RxNorm API now has a method that will do matching of text that only approximately matches the RxNorm concept. See http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/RxNormAPI.html#label:23